# how to make navigator.vibrate to work on Onload when page loads

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make the phone/device to vibrate when the page loads. Right now the vibrate is working only when we click the button to vibrate.,

But the `onload` tag it is not working. Give me a solution to fix this.

I have even tired by adding `window.onload = example1();` too. But still not working.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           function example1() {
             // Vibrate for 500ms
             navigator.vibrate([500]);
           }
        </script>     
    </head>
    <body onload="example1()">
        <div><button onclick="example1()">Vibrate</button></div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

When the page loads, phone/device should vibrate based on the time interval we set it.

Comment: that would rather be `window.onload = example1;` (without brackets) or else you instantly call the function an attribute the result to `onload` instead of binding the function

Comment: @Kaddath thanks for the help, :( but it still not working,

Comment: Have you tried to give an id to the button and trigger the button click in the `onload` function? If it still doesn't work, you're maybe in the case where such action requires a user input, like it was done with playing videos tags on mobile..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You can't,

In Chrome, this method requires an [user gesture](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#triggered-by-user-activation).

Here is an excerpt of the motivations from [the crbug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=704650) which implemented this measure.

> The vibrate API is abused by sites and ads for social engineering, and we'd like to gate vibrate with user activation (aka. user gesture or user initiated actions) to better protect user.

So doing it onload is not possible.

---

In Firefox, they did choose to ask for user's confirmation on a per domain basis, this means that for this browser, you could, at second load trigger this method, but the user would have had to click "accept" on a prompt message from a previous visit.

This is by the way in accordance with the [W3C recommendations](https://w3c.github.io/vibration/#security-and-privacy-considerations) which is more concerned  about privacy for some convoluted reasons.

For other browsers, I'm not sure they even support this method.

Comment: Alright i get the part :) thanks for the answer. But this is for the chat room, we get lot of spammers who use mobile phone and keep switching ip instantly. If we have this vibrate trigger option enabled. so we can make their mobile phones vibrate for certain period, and keep them away from chat room by spamming the room. Let me know if you have any idea to implement this action.