# Vibrate device on loading the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload, vibration

I can vibrate the device on click:

```js
$(".button").vibrate({
  duration: 2000,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://illyism.github.io/jquery.vibrate.js/build/jquery/jquery.vibrate.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">Try It!</div>
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tyn3m059/2)

But, I need to start the vibration onload so I tried [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tyn3m059/3). But it didn't work!

Comment: is not because your jquery selector is empty? try  navigator.vibrate(2000);

Comment: I swapped your script tags in your snippet

Comment: @SamuelTeixeira I tried,https://jsfiddle.net/tyn3m059/6/ but it's not working

Comment: Some browsers require the user to interact with the page first. Answerd before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54111961/11303992)

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger a click or similar - if the browser allows it. [Likely it won't.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54111304/how-to-make-navigator-vibrate-to-work-on-onload-when-page-loads)

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").vibrate({
    duration: 2000,
  }).trigger("touchstart");
});
```

Comment: I need vibration as soon as the page is loaded. (not on touch or click)

Comment: I understand but your plugin only attaches to something you can click so I attached it AND clicked it on load

Comment: Doesn't work, https://jsfiddle.net/tyn3m059/8/

Comment: Then you are SOL

Comment: I couldn't get the full form of SOL